# How do I suspend execution of JS in browser debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I can suspend execution of Java in Eclipse debugger.
Can I do the same with JavaScript in browser debugger?

Comment: Are you talking about breakpoints? If so, [here's the documentation on them](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/).

Comment: No. I am a Java developer. I can suspend execution of Java in Eclipse debugger.

Comment: @isobretatel you can suspend javascript execution with breakpoints as well

Comment: If you're talking about the equivalent of the pause button in Eclipse you can press that instantly pauses execution wherever it happens to be, it's under the "Sources" tab on the left side about half way down the page.

Comment: "No. I am a Java developer. I can suspend execution of Java in Eclipse debugger." What does that mean? lol

Comment: You can add `debugger` statement in the code to stop the execution, but it's not clear what's wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the Sources tab of the browser Developer Tools, click on the pause button ⏸️ to suspend JavaScript execution.

The above is for Google Chrome. It might be slightly different in Firefox or Safari.